# Doesn't MySite automatically pick data from UPS or AD?

Tags: 2013, my-site

I just created MySite in SharePoint 2013.

I saw that it shows the user name, department, phone etc. but not the picture. Shouldn't it automatically pick picture also like other fields?

Secondly how can I branding of MySite?

Thirdly how can I, as an administrator, apply same branding on all user mysites and they shouldn't be able to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I know the picture won't be synchronised automatically from AD. You have to define a mapping between "Picture" property in the user profile and a property in AD. Then run the user profile synchronisation again.
2. and 3.  You can iterate through all my sites in powershell and apply the desired branding to your my site (e.g. set master page etc.) This will however not apply to the newly created mysites, This can be done through feature stapling and custom development.
3. The users are sadly site collection administrators in theirs my sites. So you will have to remove this permission from the users and assign them new lower permission. However I would not mess up with the permissions unless you really need to it can bring side effects.